# How do I sign into the IRS to check the status of my refund?

Tags: united-states, irs, income-tax-refund

I would like to check on the status of my refund. I have a username and password for the IRS written down, but I can't find the login page.

Comment: Are you trying to check the status of your refund for last year (tax year 2015)?

Answer (score 4):

The IRS's [Where's My Refund?](https://www.irs.gov/refunds) tool does not use a username and password.  Instead, you enter your social security number, your filing status, and the exact amount of the refund you requested on your tax return.